# angular animate, slide in right slide out left

Tags: angularjs, css, animation, ng-show

i want to do a animation with ng-show and css transitions, where the container slides from RIGHT side to the center and then from the center to LEFT side.

here my code:

```
<span class="test" ng-show="showContainer == 'first'">Content One</span>
<span class="test" ng-show="showContainer == 'second'">Content Two</span>
<span class="test" ng-show="showContainer == 'third'">Content Three</span>
```

css:

```
.test { 
    left: 0px;
    @include transition(left, 5s, ease-in-out);
}

.test.ng-hide { left: 2000px;}
```

So I wonder if there is something possible like

```
.test.ng-hide-active { left: -2000px; }
```

At the moment it slides from the right to the center and then it goes back to the right.

Is it possible with css and ng-show?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, i figured it out, it works with the `.ng-hide-add-active` class!
angular rules!